# Update index of a stride loop inside another

Tags: swift, loops

Due to the complexity of the calculation I have to update indexes inside multiple `for loops`.

So,

```
for index in stride(from: 0, to: data.count, by: 1)
   .....
   .....

    for i in stride(from: index, to: data.count, by: 1)
        .....
        index=i ; break;  //update index and break inner loop so next outer for loop iteration will start from a new index.
```

So the outer loop will now jump to a new value.

Using `"where"` in the loop is not possible because the condition in the inner loop depend on too many things. ( it's not just where `i != 2`)

1. I will get an error that index is let
2. Is this a bad practice  ?

Comment: Can you give us a more concrete example of what these loops do? I'd say ~80% of the time they can be replaced with map, filter or reduce calls.

Comment: thanks, you are right, but the code inside the loop is too complex and long to put here. Basically I am looping on data with many dates manipulations, so for example I need to loop based on a time frame, so I have to first read every date, then ask if it is larger than some window, if so, break the loop. So I can't just loop per element in array, because I have to extract data from the element first, in order to know the limits of the loop . .

Comment: Just past the code into a paste on some site like pastebin.com, and link it in a comment. "so I have to first read every date, then ask if it is larger than some window, if so, break the loop." sounds like a `contains` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by replacing the first stride with a `while`.

```
var index = 0

while index < data.count {
    .....
    .....
    index += 1
    for i in stride(from: index-1, to: data.count, by: 1) {
        .....
        index=i 
        break
    }
}
```